# QGIS project in Lizmap showing only points vector layers

Tags: qgis-server, vector-layer, lizmap

I am trying to set up a QGIS project in Lizmap, but the problem is that I can't see polygons or lines vector layers.

They appear in the legend; I can zoom on them or use "select by location"; and I can edit them: I can change the attributes and even add new features. The features I add in Lizmap are correctly displayed if I open my layers in QGIS using WFS/WMS or PostGIS, and are saved in my attribute tables. But they are not visible in Lizmap (they "disappear" as soon as I finish drawing them in Lizmap).

The problem doesn't arise with "point" geometry: my points vector layers are correctly displayed in Lizmap, even if they have a complex symbology (heatmap). Raster layers (eg orthophotograph used as base layer) also display correctly.
I did a few tests, and I have the same problem for shape layers used as base layers: they only show if their geometry type is "point".

I have no idea where the problem comes from.

Comment: Did you watch error.log in lizmap/var/log ?

Comment: Yes. There was nothing out of the ordinary. I ended up doing a re-install with a 64 bits version (I was using a 32 bits Lizmap container on a Raspberry 3 + hypriot 32 bits) and it worked. I didn't put it as an answer because it's more of a workaround than a real explanation of what was going wrong...